# Signification de "slope" dans le langage informatique

Tags: traduction, anglais, sens, expressions-idiomatiques

[Lu sur un autre forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/140758/47212)
1° Aveu d'ignorance :

> *Nobody knows what the slope of the line means*

2° Utilisation d'une inconnue :

> *A steeper distribution [larger magnitude of the slope] suggests a preference for less complex methods*

Je n'arrive pas à décoder quelle notion sous-tend ce mot, lorsqu'il s'agit d'analyser ou de comparer les façons de programmer en Java.

Un rapport avec l'indentation, la longueur des lignes, l'aspect formel du code ?
Un jargon uniquement informatique, ou un référence poétique/littéraire cachée ?

N.B. : Aux anglophones : je ne sais écrire qu'en français, mais j'arrive à lire l'anglais ... réponse(s) '*confortable*' souhaitée(s).

Comment: Cette question concerne le sens d'un mot anglais, elle serait sûrement plus à sa place sur http://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Evpok pour avoir la réponse du sens en anglais? ... alors que Stam a fourni une interprétation approuvée au moins 8 fois ??? fermez, fermez si vous voulez, maintenant que j'ai compris, mais pensez aussi aux autres francophones qui subissent l'anglais, et sont plus à l'aise dans d'autres langues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le mot *« slope »* n'a pas de sens informatique. Il est utilisé ici dans son sens mathématique car, d'après le lien, la personne trace une courbe sur un graphique pour analyser des données abstraites de manière plus visuelle.

La première phrase signifie donc :

> *Personne ne sait ce que signifie la pente de la droite.*

Et la deuxième :

> *Une plus forte distribution [pente plus élevée] suggère une préférence pour des méthodes moins complexes.*

Ce que permet de voir cette courbe est la complexité du code informatique analysé, c'est-à-dire le nombre d'embranchements possibles.

Comment: Très clair, merci pour les traductions.

Comment: Sauf que "steep" signifie "pentu" donc "steeper distribution" = plus pentue, pas "plus forte"

Comment: @boisvert C'est vrai. Pourrait-on traduire par _« distribution plus incurvée »_ (puisque c'est avant d'aplatir la courbe avec les échelles logarithmiques) ? Je modifierai ma réponse si cela convient.

Comment: Une pente plus marquee? Il y a une difference interessante entre l'anglais et le francais ici, parce que "steep" appartient a un registre a la fois familier et formel.

Comment: @boisvert Oui, c'est ce que ça veut dire, mais je voulais éviter la répétition du mot _« pente »_ (car _« steep »_ et _« slope »_ produisent la même traduction ici). Sinon, selon moi, on ne comprend pas très bien ce qu'apporte la précision entre crochets.